# SQLite python error again

Tags: python, sqlite

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
print " "
choice = raw_input("Does the Customer know their user ID? Y/N : ")
if choice == "N":
        number = raw_input("What is their phone number? : ")
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Telephone = (?)", (number,))
        row = cur.fetchone()
        print "Customer ID : " , row[0]
```

I use the code above in order to retrieve customer details - but i get the following error when i do it :

```
  File "G:\ICT\SADS.py", line 111, in editdetails
print "Customer ID : " , row[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and its really getting on my nerves ive tried using while loops or for row in rows yet it does not work - please help :(

Comment: Are you sure the telephone number you entered is in the table?

Comment: Seems it can't find a customer with the entered phone number.

Comment: I suggest creating the query using string formatting and printing out the query to verify the query. Also check to see what format the entries in the Telephone column are in (222.222.2222/(222)222-2222/etc) and show that format to the user.

Comment: @JamesThiele: No! Do not use string formatting when SQL parameters can be used instead. SQL parameters give the database the opportunity to plan the query (and reuse the plan), and give the client library the chance to quote correctly and thus prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
row = cur.fetchone()
if row is None:
    print "Telephone number not found"
else:
    print "Customer ID : " , row[0]
```